# How to delay a part of a function when widgets are involved?

Tags: python, tkinter

(Sorry for bad english)
Hello! I'm new to programming. I'm having some trouble using the "after" method, I use Tkinter.

So, I want a function to execute a part of the code and then delay the rest but it just freezes and executes everything at once.

```py
def click1 ():
    entered_text=textentry.get()
    textentry.delete(0, "end")
    try:
        rasp1 = inputs[entered_text]
    except:
        rasp1 = "Hello, " + entered_text + "!"
    textentry.destroy()
    enter.destroy()
    tk.Label(root,
             text=entered_text + " <<",
             fg="white",
             bg="#333333",
             #aspect=1000,
             justify="left",
             font=courier) .grid(column=1, sticky="e")
    root.after(3000)
    Rasp1 = tk.Message(root,
                       text=">> " + rasp1,
                       fg="#00ff00",
                       bg="#333333",
                       aspect=800,
                       justify="left",
                       font=courier)
    Rasp1.grid(column=1, sticky="w")
```

I tried to write the callback as the function, as I've seen on other programs, but that would give an error:

```py
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1547, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 596, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "C:\create\Jim(grid).exe.py", line 38, in click1
    entered_text=textentry.get()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2518, in get
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'get')
TclError: invalid command name ".31959040"
```

Comment: Read about [`w.wait_variable(var), w.wait_visibility(window), w.wait_window(window)`](effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing what you want but I think the code below will help.

Your after needs to be `root.after(3000, callback)`. I've moved the `Rasp1...` code into a function `do_after` this is called by root 3 seconds after root.after is executed.  The point of `after` is that it doesn't delay execution of anything in the GUI.  It allows the rest of the GUI to remain active to text input, clicks, etc. while the program delays starting the execution of it's callback.

```
import tkinter as tk

def click1 ():
    global rasp1
    entered_text=textentry.get()
    textentry.delete(0, "end")
    rasp1 = "Hello, " + entered_text + "!"
    textentry.destroy()
    enter.destroy()
    tk.Label(root,
             text=entered_text + " <<",
             fg="white",
             bg="#333333",
             #aspect=1000,
             justify="left").grid(row = 2, column=1, sticky="e")
    root.after(3000, do_after )

def do_after():
    Rasp1 = tk.Message(root,
                       text=">> " + rasp1,
                       fg="#00ff00",
                       bg="#333333",
                       aspect=800,
                       justify="left")
    Rasp1.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="w")

root = tk.Tk()
textentry = tk.Entry(root)
textentry.grid()
enter = tk.Button(root, command = click1, text = " Test " )
enter.grid()
root.mainloop()
```